# Does PySpark offer advantage when data size is bigger than memory?

Tags: apache-spark

Does PySpark offer any advantage when working with data that is too big to be completely loaded into memory? I'm trying to compare this (and other features) to an approach based on IPy Parallel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

spark-shell(uses scala)/ pyspark are meant for Superfast cluster computing.

It all depends on how much is the size of cluster especially the SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY you are going to assign to each worker.

If your data is more that what it is to fit into memory, spark will make use of DISK (along with memory) efficiently.

hope this helps :)

Comment: + choose RDD Persistence storagelevel based on your requirement